# Eclipse- Android storm .apt_generated not include in Dex file

Tags: android, eclipse

I try to use Storm [http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/storm-preview/] android orm.

My java classes have been generated with this method (DataBaseHelper, Dao...).

But when I launched my application on my Sansung Device, I had this type of an exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : com... Dao

This class has been generated by storm and I can find in my .apt_generated folder.

I think Eclipse doesn't generate my Dex file with storm classes generated.

Have you any advices to resolve this problem ?

Thank you in advance for your responses.